# BigQuery - How to select a condition within a group

Tags: google-bigquery

I have records as below, with `user_id`, `date`, `country`, etc.
Some of the countries are 'unknown'. When I group by `user_id`, I want to be able to return the next value after unknown, if one exists. If not, return unknown.

So, from input data like this:

```
user_id  |   date     | country | gender
----------------------------------------
   A       2015-10-01   unknown     M
   A       2015-10-02      US       M
   B       2015-10-01      CA       M
   B       2015-10-02      US       M
   C       2015-10-04      US       M
   C       2015-10-06      US       M
```

I would like a single query that would return:

```
   date     | country | gender | num_users
-------------------------------------------
 2015-10-02      US       M          2
 2015-10-01      CA       M          1
 2015-10-04      US       M          1
```

I'm currently using a normal `GROUP EACH BY` but this can't take into consideration the unknowns.

```
SELECT
  FIRST(date),
  FIRST(country),
  COUNT(DISTINCT user_id,50000000) AS num_users
FROM
  my_table
WHERE
  date BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND CURRENT_DATE()
GROUP BY
  date,
  country
```

I'm using BigQuery, but could likely adapt any solution.
Any thoughts? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to solve it. The example shows both cases when all countries are "unknown" for same user and when only some of them are unknown

```
select 
  user_id,
  first(date), 
  ifnull(first(if(country = "unknown", null, country)), "unknown") from
(select "A" user_id, "2015-10-01" date, "unknown" country),
(select "A" user_id, "2015-10-02" date, "unknown" country),
(select "B" user_id, "2015-10-01" date, "CA" country),
(select "B" user_id, "2015-10-02" date, "US" country),
(select "C" user_id, "2015-10-04" date, "unknown" country),
(select "C" user_id, "2015-10-06" date, "US" country)
group by user_id
```